# Remove action 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table' not working

Tags: wordpress, email, hook, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I am trying to remove the "Our bank information" and payment instructions from Woocommerce BACS gateway thankyou page and emails.

I know it should be done simply by removing the woocommerce_thankyou_bacs and  woocommerce_email_before_order_table action.

I managed to remove the message from thankyou page, but it still appears in the emails. I checked, woocommerce_thankyou_bacs and woocommerce_email_before_order_table are both removed from wp_filter global.

I am relying on a function i copied from here: http://wpquestions.com/question/showChrono/id/9204 due to having similar problem of remove_action not working due to different unique id, and it works, in a way that the actions are gone from wp_filter global.

I have tried all kind of priorities, 0-20, the thankyou page message is gone but email still shows the payment instructions.

My code is as follows:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_bacs', function() {
    if( function_exists( 'wc_gateway_remove_hook' ) ) {
        //Remove BACS payment instructions from thankyou page <- WORKS!
        wc_gateway_remove_hook( 'WC_Gateway_BACS', 'woocommerce_thankyou_bacs', 'thankyou_page' );
        //Remove BACS payment instructions from email <- DOESN'T WORK!
        wc_gateway_remove_hook( 'WC_Gateway_BACS', 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'email_instructions' );  

    }
}, 10 );

function wc_gateway_remove_hook( $classname, $hook, $callback ) {
    foreach( (array) $GLOBALS['woocommerce']->payment_gateways->payment_gateways as $key => $gateway_obj ) {
        if( $classname === get_class( $gateway_obj ) ) {
            remove_action( $hook, array( $gateway_obj, $callback ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', function() {
    if( function_exists( 'wc_gateway_remove_hook' ) ) {
        wc_gateway_remove_hook( 'WC_Gateway_BACS', 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'email_instructions' );
    }
}, 10);

function wc_gateway_remove_hook( $classname, $hook, $callback ) {
    foreach( (array) $GLOBALS['woocommerce']->payment_gateways->payment_gateways as $key => $gateway_obj ) {
        if( $classname === get_class( $gateway_obj ) ) {
            remove_action( $hook, array( $gateway_obj, $callback ) );
        }
    }
}
```